# How to solve error popping up when opening Synpatic package manager

Tags: synaptic

Error is this:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_jd
team_jdownloader_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

I tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it (first answer) but even from command line I keep getting the very same error at each command (except for sudo dpkg --configure -a)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

from

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=863742&p=7911230#post7911230